# Dynamically using a class for a static variable in Android

Tags: java, android

I had a question for using a variable in a way that it would be used by the caller.

Here’s my dilemma:

```
Activity A {
 Static variable X;
  D(); //calls static method from Activity C.
 }

 Activity B {
  Static variable X; //same name as A but initialized differently.
  D(); //calls static method from Activity C.
 }

 Activity C {

   static Method D {
     //Say I want to use variable B here and call some method. But I want to use it dynamically depending on who called C. 
    // So it should be either A.X.getCount() or B.X.getCount().

   }
 }
```

I thought this.X.getCount() would work but it can't since D is static.
Is there an ideal way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why is variable x static if you want to use in a non-static way?

Comment: Why not parameter  X as params to D ?

Comment: Perhaps make interface Z with variable X, implement Z on A and B, change X on both A and B, pass it to C.D, and call z.getCount(). Not sure if this is what you're looking for

Comment: Maybe you could just do C.D()   if D is static. Not sure